# Creating a stored procedure to remove all constraints before truncating all data and restoring the data without dropping the database

Tags: sql-server

Dropping the database requires exclusive access to the Database which isn't feasible in my scenario as I am testing another program which has access to the DB at the same time.

The issue I am having is that I can't truncate every tables data unless all constraints are removed which I can achieve using

`EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? DROP CONSTRAINT FOREIGNKEY"`

except that where `FOREIGNKEY` is I need to provide the name of the foreign key which is different for every table.

I can find the constraint name using sql using 
`select CONSTRAINT_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` but I'm not sure how to combine these two pieces of data

Solution:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="DELETE FROM ?"
GO
```

Delete From doesn't require dropping constraints like truncate does.

Comment: Seems like you have to query per table. Find key (in order) and remove constraint and run truncate.

Comment: You should use a cursor for finding FK constraints and dropping them. Note that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS contains not only FK, but also CHECK, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY constraints

Comment: This tip should help here, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/

Comment: Why not simply issue a bunch of `DELTE FROM table` instead of `TRUNCATE`? It doesn't need to drop the constraints.

Comment: @Alejandro I didn't know that delete didn't require dropping constraints, Thanks!

Comment: You just have to delete the data by deleting the children first. Then if you want to reseed any indentities you would also need to do that.

Comment: @Alejandro >>>Why not simply issue a bunch of DELTE FROM table instead of TRUNCATE?<<< 1. Because DELETE is always **fully logged**. If you have to purge 1Tb of the data, you'll truncate the entire db in 5 minutes but it will take about 1 day to DELETE this data 2. Can you suggest a script that will effectively find all the children of all the parent tables in a database? I mean fully automated script for thousands of tables

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already scripted the constraints to be able to rebuild them after dropping them - if not do this before dropping them!

Then execute the query in a dynamic SQL loop which reads the constraint list sequentially. Example below (you may want to adjust the @SQL variable, I have commented out the execution and replaced it by a print so that you can safely execute it to see what it does).

```
DECLARE @ConstraintList TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, constraint_name VARCHAR(255), table_name VARCHAR(255), constraint_type VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @ConstraintList (constraint_name, table_name, constraint_type) SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
DECLARE @constraint_name VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @constraint_type VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @j INT
SET @i = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @ConstraintList)
SET @j = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @ConstraintList)
WHILE @i <= @j
BEGIN 
    SET @constraint_name = (SELECT constraint_name FROM @ConstraintList WHERE ID = @i)
    SET @table_name = (SELECT table_name FROM @ConstraintList WHERE ID = @i)
    SET @constraint_type = (SELECT constraint_type FROM @ConstraintList WHERE ID = @i)
    SET @SQL = ('ALTER TABLE '+@table_name+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+@constraint_name+' FOREIGNKEY') 
    -- EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT @SQL 
SET @i = @i+1
END
```

Comment: The Print worked perfect but when I've gone to exec it comes back with Could not find stored procedure 'ALTER TABLE dbo.Brand DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Brand_HoldingCompany FOREIGNKEY'

Comment: @JackTyler add `USE YourDBName; ` in front of `ALTER TABLE` and `EXEC(@sql)`

Comment: Original answer had `EXEC @SQL` when it needs to be `EXEC (@SQL)` that is why you got the stored procedure error.  I have updated.

Comment: That's correct, EXEC needs a quoted query in paranthesis. Take one of the prints and put it into a EXEC ('printed output') to try